# How can I let compiler to deduce a type of nullptr?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++.
I would like to let compiler to deduce nullptr as shared_ptr.
Please read the following code,

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
};

struct Tag {
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
};

auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) {
    if (tag) {
        auto& sharedB = *(tag->b);
        return sharedB.a;
    } else {
        return nullptr;  // Error : compiler cannot deduce type of nullptr.
    }
}
```

In `GetSharedPtrClassB`, `nullptr` cannot be deduced as `std::shared_ptr<A>`.
The error messages are following,

```
error: inconsistent deduction for ‘auto’: ‘std::shared_ptr<A>’ and then ‘std::nullptr_t’
```

How can I let compiler deduce nullptr as `std::shared_ptr<A>`?
 I can provide a type `decltype(*(tag->b))`, but I cannot think of the next step to provide a type `std::shared_ptr<A>`.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How about explicitly using `std::shared_ptr<A>` as the  return type? Or returning a default constructed `std::shared_ptr<A>` object in the `else` case?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude:thank you for commenting it. In my actual code, class A can be C because of meta programming. So I would like to let deduce type of shared_ptr<'X'>.

Comment: It is better to show the actual problem because now everyone need to guess which approach suits best ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))... Also see how to ask a good question: [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a conditional operator to force the conversion from `nullptr` to "whatever":

```
auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) {
    return tag ? tag->b->a : nullptr;
}
```

---

Conversion from one operand to the other in a conditional operator is well-defined (see *[expr.cond]*), here the `nullptr` gets converted to an object of type `decltype(tag->b->a)`.

On the other hand, the rules for return type deduction when using `auto` without a trailing return type are very strict - the deduced type must be the same for each `return` statement (*[dcl.spec.auto/9]*):

> If a function with a declared return type that contains a placeholder type has multiple return statements,
>   the return type is deduced for each return statement. If the type deduced is not the same in each deduction,
>   the program is ill-formed.

---

If your function cannot be reduced to a conditional operator, you can use a trailing return type:

```
auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) -> decltype(tag->b->a) {
    if (tag) {
        auto& sharedB = *(tag->b);
        return sharedB.a;
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the most functional suggestion, I feel

Comment: @sehe I think I found something even better, see edit ;)

Comment: @Holt: thank you for answering. But it give me an error "eturning initializer list".

Comment: @mora I have updated the answer with a much simpler version - In the other approach, did you add the trailing return type correctly (`decltype` after the function)?

Comment: @mora it should be fine http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b84d7436e4c8449f and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d04ea3a0fd12cca3

Comment: @Holt: I did not add -> decltype(tag->b->a). It was my mistake. Your code works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can return a default constructed shared_ptr instead.

```
auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) {
    if (tag) {
        auto& sharedB = *(tag->b);
        return sharedB.a;
    } else {
        return std::shared_ptr<A>{};
    }
}
```

Comment: :thank you for commenting it. In my actual code, class A can be C because of meta programming. So I would like to let deduce type of shared_ptr<'X'>.

Comment: @mora - Sorry for being AFK. The answer by Holt is exactly what you should do to add deduction. I suggest you accept that answer.

Comment: it was my less explanation. Your answer is one of solution for me. Thank you for answering it again.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that your code is actually use in a generic context. If your code don't use templates don't use decltype, specify types directly.

To deduce the return type, all return statements *must* evaluate to an expression of the same type. In your code, you have two return statements with two different types. One with `std::shared_ptr<A>`, and one with `std::nullptr_t`.

There is two solution: use the same types in both return statements, or explicitly define a return type.

Here's how to return the same type:

```
auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) {
    if (tag) {
        auto& sharedB = *(tag->b);
        return sharedB.a;
    }

    // empty constructor same as initializing with `nullptr`
    return decltype(tag->b->a){};
}
```

Or explicitly define a return type:

```
auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) -> decltype(tag->b->a) {
    if (tag) {
        auto& sharedB = *(tag->b);
        return sharedB.a;
    }

    // empty constructor same as initializing with `nullptr`
    return {};
}
```

By the way, in you code `auto& sharedB = *(tag->b); return sharedB.a;` could be reduced to `return tag->b->a;`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `static_cast` like this:

```
auto GetSharedPtrClassB(Tag* tag) {
    if (tag) {
        auto& sharedB = *(tag->b);
        return sharedB.a;
    } else {
        return static_cast<std::shared_ptr<A> >(nullptr);
    }
}
```

Comment: :thank you for commenting it. In my actual code, class A can be C because of meta programming. So I would like to let deduce type of shared_ptr<'X'>.